# How to tell xsd.exe to use a specific .NET type for a custom xs:simpleType?

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xsd.exe

In my XSD I have some type definitions like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Ref_System">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[a-fA-F0-9]{8}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{4}-[a-fA-F0-9]{12}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Obviously, this defines a UUID. However, since the `xs:simpleType` is based on `xs:string`, the `xsd.exe` tool will create a `string` property for elements using this type `Ref_System`.

The following `xs:complexType`...

```
<xs:complexType name="Incident">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="system" type="Ref_System" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
        <!-- ... -->
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

...will result in the following C# class:

```
public partial class Incident {
    private string systemField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order=0)]
    public string system {
        get {
            return this.systemField;
        }
        set {
            this.systemField = value;
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is there any way to tell the `xsd.exe` tool to generate `Guid` properties for elements which use the `Ref_System` type?

**Note:** It is not an option to change the XSD file since this is coming from an external source!

**Note 2:** I know that I can extend the `partial class`, define a custom `Guid` property in there and then convert the `string` property to the `Guid` property using `XmlConvert.ToGuid(...)`. However, since I have lots of cases like this, I would like to avoid the manual work and use an automated approach instead.

Comment: Could using <xs:element name="Ref_System" type="xs:guid" /> inside Incident help?

Comment: @NahumTimerman That might help, but as I noted at the end: "It is not an option to change the XSD file since this is coming from an external source!"

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is interested in a solution: I didn't find any way to tell `xsd.exe` to use another type in scenarios like this. Generally, `xsd.exe` seems to be very inflexible. That's why I looked for other tools and found the [XmlSchemaClassGenerator](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator) project. This offers great flexibility, [supports Nullable natively](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator#nullables), supports separate files per class (using [`Generator.SeparateClasses`](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/blob/cc03fe41c5ed9939fd6d94795057770093f43e12/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/Generator.cs#L262)), has lots of other nice features and provides quite some extension points. Furthermore, it is open source, so that you can adjust it to your needs if the available options are not sufficient.

In my case, I created a simple Console application and consumed the library NuGet package. See the ["Usage" section of the project's Readme](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator#usage) for details (scroll down to the paragraph starting with "For use from code...").

I used the [`Generator.MemberVisitor`](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/blob/cc03fe41c5ed9939fd6d94795057770093f43e12/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/Generator.cs#L217) or [`Generator.TypeVisitor`](https://github.com/mganss/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/blob/cc03fe41c5ed9939fd6d94795057770093f43e12/XmlSchemaClassGenerator/Generator.cs#L226) to make the generator use `System.Guid` for properties of type `Ref_System`. Unfortunately, I can't provide details or code since I changed to another company in the meantime, but it was not that complicated.